# What does this mean: "All these years and I don't know who he is anymore than he knows who i am."

Tags: meaning

> All these years and I don't know who he is anymore than he knows who i am.

Does it mean: I don't know him anymore and he does not know me either?

Comment: The words **any more** should be separate here. It's a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is incorrect. "anymore" should be two words.

> ... I don't know who he is any more than he knows who I am.

The implied break is in the middle, after "is".

In other words, I don't know who he is, and neither does he know who I am.